# vuejs-parent and child components

Tags: vue.js

I am new in vuejs and Iam coding in  laravel 
I have watched vuejs tutorial but I have got a little confused
about parent and child components because when I started coding in laravel I just used a simple component and use it in blade and 
I didn't feel needing parent component I want the usage and when to use
parent component because there were lots of documention for parent and child component I dont know when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

parent component and child component is not the same, child component feeding by the parent as the prop, you can mutate data to child component by parent and emit data from child to parent for changed the prop.

for example:

```
 ////parent.vue////

 <parent-component>
    <child-component :item="items"  :profile="profile"></child-component>
</parent-component>

export default {
  data(){
      items: {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Negar'
 },
 data2: {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Hozhabr^_^'
 }
},
 profile: {
    url: 'http://www.alibaba.com',
    company: 'alibaba',
    city: 'Tehran'
  }
}

//// child.vue /////
<template> 
    Item: {{items}}

    profile: {{profile}}
</template>

export default {
  props:['items', 'profile']
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but I know what u said my question is s.th else 
I mean when to use parent and child component I don't really feel needing parent and child I just code in one component

Comment: I explain more for it if you want to share data between 5 same components you can't share data between them and all of them are independent else if you create a parent component you can create 5 components as the child and feeds them by the parent as the prop, In this case, you created the relationship between all of the child via parent.